# How to configure GRUB4DOS

Tags: linux, grub, bootloader, easybcd, grub4dos

I've integrated GRUB4DOS into my Windows 7 bootloader menu using EasyBCD.

It works and I can chainload to my Linux GRUB at `/dev/sda5` (`(hd0,4)`) but I have to do it manually every time.  Grub4Dos just gives me its command prompt and I have to enter

```
chainloader (hd0,4)+1
boot
```

by hand every time I boot.

How to automate this?

I don't want to install GRUB to MBR and make it my primary boot loader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just edit EasyBCD's NeoGrub configuration file.

Click the configure button in the image below:

[image: Configuring EasyBCD's NeoGrub]

And notepad will open with the configuration file loaded. Paste your boot code into there, save, and exit.

(Image taken from [linuxso's EasyBCD page](http://www.linuxso.com/windows/14503.html))

Comment: Thanks. I shall try this. I have actually used "Linux/BSD" page that time.

Answer (score 0):

Although this has an accepted answer, FYI: GRUB4DOS [has](https://rmprepusb.com/tutorials/021-guide-to-grub4dos/) a hardcoded init script in its last 512 bytes of `grldr`. By default that loads `menu.lst` (which it tries to find in a few places: `/`, `/boot/grub/`, and `/grub/`) at least in version 0.4.5c.

So simply pasting those lines you wanted in a `menu.lst` file in one of those places (relative to the drive where `grldr` gets loaded from) is the direct way. From what I can [read](https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/neogrub/) about EasyBCD (which is the method suggested in the accepted answer) it uses an unmodified grub4dos these days (still branded as "NeoGRUB") so it probably treats them the same, config wise.